# How to click a class or div in Javascript

Tags: javascript, roblox

I need help with this, I'm making a bot for a game but the button doesn't have an ID and I need to click it.

```
<div id="BuyWithRobux">
    <div data-expected-currency="1" 
         data-asset-type="T-Shirt" 
         class="btn-primary btn-medium PurchaseButton" 
         data-se="item-buyforrobux" 
         data-item-name="Donate" 
         data-item-id="168062114" 
         data-expected-price="2" 
         data-product-id="20627571" 
         data-expected-seller-id="64334066" 
         data-bc-requirement="0" 
         data-seller-name="Doxact">
            Buy with R$
            <span class="btn-text">Buy with R$</span>
    </div>                                    
</div>
```

Code I'm using right now:

```
var id = itemID;
window.location.replace("roblox.com/--item?id=" + id);

document.onload = function() {
    $("#BuyWithRobux > span.btn-text").click();
    document.getElementById("roblox-confirm-btn").click();
};
```

Comment: If you need to click a button, start by placing the mouse pointer over the button on the screen. Then, click the left button on your mouse, and you've clicked the button, tada !

Comment: So... what do you want the click to do?

Comment: @Adeneo Seriously? Can you not read? I am trying to create a BOT for a game, it does it automatically, I'm trying to use javascript to do it.

Comment: @kevin I just want it to click it

Comment: @user3920245 - I can read, and it's unclear what you're asking, other than "how to click a button" ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery, this is fairly trivial.

```
$("span.btn-text").click();
```

If your page has more than one span with the btn-text style, you can select using lineage filters:

```
$("#BuyWithRobux>span.btn-text").click();
```

If you aren't using jquery, this might work:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("btn-text")[0].click();
```

Comment: still not working, maybe it's something with my code, I'm fairly new to javascript and just find everything off the internet and try learn 



var id = itemID
window.location.replace('http://www.roblox.com/--item?id='+id);
document.onload = function(){
$("#BuyWithRobux>span.btn-text").click();
document.getElementById("roblox-confirm-btn").click();
};

Comment: Have you included jquery on your page?

Comment: Doing it through console in google chrome, not sure how, as I said I'm pretty new.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.btn-text').click()
```

use this

Answer (score 0):

Ok, ill help more then

maybe you should use this

```
function scan(max) {
        $.get(link, function(wowow) {
                var Price = wowow[0]['BestPrice'];
        var Name = wowow[0]['Name'];
                if (Price <= max) {
                        console.log("The item is up for "+Price);
                        $.get("http://www.roblox.com"+wowow[0]['Url'], function(wowow) {
                                var info = $($("<div>").html(wowow.replace(/img/gi,"flip")).find('.ItemSalesTable tr')[0]).find('.PurchaseButton').data();
                                var buy = 'http://www.roblox.com/'+ locations + info['productId'] + '&expectedCurrency=1&expectedPrice=' + info['expectedPrice'] + '&expectedSellerId=' + info['expectedSellerId'] + '&userAssetID=' + info['userassetId'];
                                if (info['expectedPrice'] <= Price) {
                                        $.post(buy).success(function(r) { console.log("Attempting to buy " + Name + " for " +info['expectedPrice']) })
var buy = 0
buy = buy + 1
console.log("Purchases: " + buy)
console.log(Name)
                                }
                        });
                }
        }).always(function() { scan(Max) });
}      
scan(Max)
```